# Mock a specific ngxs store select with ngxs

Tags: angular, jestjs, ngxs

In the component there are two ngxs selectors:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'some-componet',
  templateUrl: './some-componet.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some-componet.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class OverviewComponent implements OnInit {

  @Select(State.foo) foo$: Observable<StateModel['foo']>;
  @Select(State.bar) bar$: Observable<StateModel['bar']>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
   
    combineLatest([foo$, bar$])
       .subscribe(([foo, bar) => {
         this.bar = bar;
       });
  }

  // left out for brevity
```

Now in the test, the following is possible:

```
describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {

    stub.state = {}

    stub.Store = {
      select: jest.fn(),
    }

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SomeComponent],
      imports: [NgxsModule.forRoot([]),
       providers: [{ provide: Store, useValue: stub.Store }]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('does something', () => {
    jest.spyOn(stub.Store, 'select')
      .mockReturnValueOnce(of(false)); // <-- this is the @Select foo$ call
      .mockReturnValueOnce(of(true)); // <-- this is the @Select bar$ call

    expect(component.bar).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

But it's not really clear that the second `.mockReturnValueOnce` is for bar$. Now it seems fine, but if I expand my spec and want different outcomes for the selectors than it becomes unclear really fast.

Is there a way to specify which select is being mocked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even better, you can use the selector apparently.

So if you have this selector:

```js
export class MySelectors {
  @Selector([State])
  static foo(state: State): string {
    return state.foo;
  }
}
```

Then you can do:

```js
jest.spyOn(stub.Store, 'select').mockImplementation(selector => {
  if (selector === MySelectors.foo) {
    return of('blaat');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Made it a little bit more readable:

```js
describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  const foo$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  const bar$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  beforeEach(async () => {

    stub.state = {}

    stub.Store = {
      select: jest.fn(),
    }

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SomeComponent],
      imports: [NgxsModule.forRoot([]),
       providers: [{ provide: Store, useValue: stub.Store }]
    }).compileComponents();

    jest.spyOn(stub.Store, 'select')
      .mockReturnValueOnce(foo$)
      .mockReturnValueOnce(bar$);
  });

  it('does something', () => {
    bar$.next(true);

    expect(component.bar).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

So at least you have some idea what's going on.

But is the @Select so obscure that nobody has a different implementation?